# Trying to achieve formatting with just divs & css instead of tables

Tags: css, html, iframe, formatting

Is there a way I can achieve the position and formatting of this iframe with only css and divs instead of the table that I am using? I tired using 3 separate divs and applied css to them and could only partially achieve this format however the bottom of the iframe would overflow and it wasn't possible to view the bottom content of the page included.

```
    <style>
      body {
        margin:0;
        background-color:#efefef;
      }
      .frame{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        border-spacing:0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      .frame_leftspace{
         width:250px;
      }
      .frame_topspace{
        height:70px;
      }
    </style>

    <table class="frame" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td class="frame_topspace" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="frame_leftspace"></td>
            <td>
            <iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="http://www.reddit.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's your issue here? http://jsbin.com/eZoNoNe/1/edit

Comment: id prefer not to use tables to achieve this formatting

Answer (score 0):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4eyzt/) will show how to achieve this. First is your original code, then how I'd recreate it:

HTML:

```
<div class="topspace"></div>
<div class="iframe">
    <iframe id="reddit" src="http://www.reddit.com/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topspace { height: 70px; }
.iframe { padding-left: 250px; }
#reddit { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

Hope that helps.